# Socket programming issue in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, networking

I have a silverlight application that is communicating with a server hosted in cloud. The application works properly when the server is listening on localhost, but when I make it listen on the server port and make my client access the socket, I get the error "Access denied"

Digging deep, I also found the error in ScopeId resolution

```
Error Code: 10045

e.RemoteEndPoint. Address.ScopeId threw an exception

The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.

at System.Net.IPAddress.get_ScopeId()
```

Thank You

Comment: Seems to be the cross domain restriction

Comment: I read somewhere about PolicyServer in case of Silverlight and Socket programming. Do you know how to work around this? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked on this side of silverlight

Comment: Do you have any guide on setting up Policy Server?

Comment: Check out: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/06/26/full-implementation-of-a-silverlight-policy-server.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"In Silverlight version 4 for a connection request using System.Net.Sockets, an application can choose instead to retrieve the policy file via the HTTP protocol on TCP port 80 instead of the custom TCP protocol on port 943. This allows HTTP servers that are already running HTTP services to authorize socket connections from Silverlight applications without having to deploy a new TCP service on the machine and open a port through a firewall for port 943."*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx

Comment: btw: would you prefer that info in a comment?  Just trying to help out.